# Crowbar Circuit for 35V OVP - What parts should I use?

Tags: fuses, specifications, over-voltage-protection

Please excuse my confusion, because I really don't understand what the "150mA max continuous cathode current" means on [the datasheet for the LM431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm431.pdf). I'm also not sure it'll work in the crowbar circuit I intend to build. (I suspect it will, seeing as it's rated for 36V).

I have the following circuit diagram, based on a Wikipedia description of a [crowbar circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(circuit)):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWkugV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D3 leads to a(n) [LM3481](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3481.pdf) used as a SEPIC (Pg 26) to output 7V for a load that draws between 500mA to 1A (1.25A to be on the safe side).

This leaves me with a number of questions, assuming I want the crowbar to reject (short out) input voltage higher than 35V:

1. If the input voltage at D1 is higher than 35V (unlikely, but possibly as high as 40V), will the LM431 become damaged or will the fuse burn out first?
2. Will a polyfuse/PTC work for F1? What part type/specifications should I look for?
3. To what should I connect the wiper for R1, GND? Does R1 *need* to be a POT or can I use a fixed resistor?
4. What are the values for R1, R2 and R3?
5. DI1 is a TRIAC. [What specifications should I look for?](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/semiconductors/discrete-semiconductors/triacs/?sra=p&rpp=100&applied-dimensions=4294817747,4294511546,4294511483,4294512041)
6. Does the 150mA mentioned in the data sheet have anything to do with the load after D3? What is it actually telling me?
7. I know that I can use `Vout ~= (1 + R1/R2)Vref` to work out what R1 and R2 should be, but I don't know how I work out `Vref`. Is that `Vin` from D1 or from the LM431?

I have seen [this as a proposed solution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53858/22572), but apparently the MOSFET doesn't short to ground (according to one of the comments).

Comment: Asking "what part(s) should I use?" is a good way to get your question closed as off-topic. Try asking something more like "what specs should I look for?" instead.

Comment: Is your goal to blow the fuse in the case of overvoltage? Do you want it to auto-reset after some specified time? Or is it good enough to have to replace a fuse each time?

Comment: @jonk Yes, the goal is to blow the fuse in the case of overvoltage (> 35V). Auto-resetting after a few seconds would be good, but I don't mind if the fuse has to be replaced once blown.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief Added something that may be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, then?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMIw6h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$Q_2\$ is a big BJT easily capable of causing the fuse to burn out in the case of an over-voltage situation. (You could try something smaller, of course. But this BJT is way more than you need to make sure.)

Here, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are used to set the threshold voltage to trigger on. I've set the threshold just a little high, just by way of an example. But you can adjust these, as needed, to hit the point you want.

\$R_3\$ is designed to provide about \$7-8\:\text{mA}\$ for the base of \$Q_1\$. Assuming \$Q_1\$ is driven into saturation, this should still mean at least \$75\:\text{mA}\$ into the base of \$Q_2\$ (and probably a lot more than that.) I might consider adding a base resistor for \$Q_2\$, but since the point is to blow the fuse I'm not sure it's really needed. If you do add it, then something like this would be fine:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSusuu.png)</sup>

That should blow the fuse.

The main thing here is to adjust the values of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to get the trigger voltage you want. Or, use a \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ potentiometer in there, as appropriate, to allow an adjustable setpoint.

The voltage across the LM431 shouldn't exceed your trip-point setting, less a diode drop or so. You could add more circuitry to make absolutely certain to protect the LM431. But this arrangement may be okay for your needs.

Comment: Thank you; much appreciated. Any suggestions on what the specifications for F1 should be?

Comment: @AgiHammerthief I think you'd suggested \$1.25\:\text{A}\$. That sounds fine to me. You could select anything from \$1\:\text{A}\$ to \$2\:\text{A}\$ (or more.) \$Q_2\$ in the circuit can sink a LOT of current on its own. And it will, if permitted.