# protect a driver for steep edges into capacitive load from external voltage

Tags: protection, mosfet-driver, trigger, push-pull

I want to have a 5V trigger output signal that has rising and falling edges of up to 200ns max. into a load of 1-5 nF.

I thought about using MOSFET driver circuits (e.g. MC33152, many suppliers have similar). They are able to actively drive to GND and VCC (in my case 5V) with fast edges (range of 10-100ns) into some nF of load.

My problem: Because this 5V trigger will be an external pin, I need to make the driver output pins robust against, accidentially connecting external voltages (20-35V) to it and I have no idea how to do it.

I thought about using a schottky diode to block voltages from outside to go into the driver output. This however would also mean, that I could no longer drive the falling adge actively (because the diode will prevent that aswell). So I would need a pulldown resistor behind the diode, but this would not be enough to get steep falling edges.

How could I protect this trigger output against externally connecting 35V to the driver output pin without losing the possibility to drive the falling edge?

Comment: How about a Zener diode in parallel?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. How would the Zener allow the lowside switch to pull to GND? Do you mean anti parallel to the schottky? Could you try to explain?

Comment: No schottky needed, only the Zener in parallel with the driver and a small series resistance to the output

Comment: some MOSFET drivers have enable inputs with 40ns delay. Could I use the zener and a transistor to pull that enable low, so that the driver will be off? I cant judge if this would be fast enough to protect the device from destruction.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami : If I follow your suggestion with a parralel zener and a series resitor. If I make it large, the protection will be good but also my signal level from the output would suffer more, because a voltage drop would appear on the resistor. If I make it small, I guess the protection will be lower. How do I know what size I should use?

Comment: Use the smallest resistor you can so not to surpass the power spec of the Zener diode. Alternatively you can use a clamping diode which can be better since its forward voltage is lower than that of a Zener http://www.circuitstoday.com/diode-clamping-circuits

Comment: Ok, I thought the clamping diode (I'm guessing you mean sth. like a TVS?) was meant to only protect against transient disturbances like ESD for example. How will I know if it can sustain a "constant" overvoltage (constant until the error is noticed and removed). The thermal stress in this case should be way higher I guess

Comment: I have found an older post about a comparable topic but related to the power supply instead of an output (as in my case).  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59666/protect-dc-circuit-from-too-much-voltage  I still have problems figuring out if this will help for my 5V ouput against a overvoltage of up to 35V.

Comment: The only solution that seems to be suggested for permanent overvoltage is some sort of fuse or PTC solution.  P.S. Sorry I wanted this to be part of my last comment, I accidentaly press enter to make a new line but instead my comment is added ^^ I'm new here and not used to this yet...