# Does an over voltage, over current and reverse polarity protection IC exist?

Tags: protection, current-limiting, polarity

I'm designing a circuit that has the following protection requirements:

- Reverse polarity
- Over voltage (60v max)
- Over current (approx 1A)

There's quite a large input voltage range, 10v to 60v.

48v is nominal, drawing about 150mA. At 10vin, it draws rougly 750mA.

---

I made and tested the following circuit to satisfy the conditions: (Values are working but not proved optimal)
[image: Protection circuit 00]

M1 was my starting point for reverse polarity, then the zener, divider & M2 were added for over voltage.

I found that D1 was needed when I breadboarded it, much to my annoyance as I wanted to avoid much voltage drop. (I smell redundancy...)

The fuse is the most frustrating element. I don't want to have to replace any components if there is a fault (even a fuse in a housing), so I was working with a PTC resettable fuse. Not only does this have an horrific tripping time (~4 seconds!), it also has a large footprint on the PCB; much too large for me I'm afraid  :(

I decided it is more beneficial to me to *monitor* the current and turn off a FET for example, than to crowbar the circuit if such a fault should occur.

**My question is...**

A) Is there an IC that can take care of these three elements? I've been looking at battery charger protection ICs but I haven't found anything yet.

B) Does anyone have a suggestion about incorporating the over current requirement in my circuit without a fuse? My initial thoughts were to use a sense resistor, comparator and another FET, but I can't help but think the whole circuit could then be simplified a great deal.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Google for "crowbar circuit". It is usually based around a SCR, which is triggered on a fault condition and in turn blows the fuse.

Comment: related thread: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/39600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this IC:
http://www.linear.com/product/LT4356-1

LT4356-1 and -2 - Surge Stopper
Features

```
Stops High Voltage Surges
Adjustable Output Clamp Voltage
Overcurrent Protection
Wide Operation Range: 4V to 80V
Reverse Input Protection to –60V
Low 7μA Shutdown Current, LT4356-1
Adjustable Fault Timer
Controls N-channel MOSFET
Shutdown Pin Withstands –60V to 100V
Fault Output Indication
Guaranteed Operation to 125°C
Auxiliary Amplifier for Level Detection Comparator or Linear Regulator Controller
Available in (4mm × 3mm) 12-Pin DFN, 10-Pin MSOP or 16-Pin SO Packages
```

You should note that the previously commended LT4361 IC is similar but does *not* support your input voltage range requirements; many ICs out there are intended to support protection of low voltage supply buses, less support the higher voltage ranges you seek.
LTC4361-1/LTC4361-2 - Overvoltage/Overcurrent Protection Controller
Features

```
2.5V to 5.5V Operation
Overvoltage Protection Up to 80V
No Input Capacitor or TVS Required for Most Applications
2% Accurate 5.8V Overvoltage Threshold
10% Accurate 50mV Overcurrent Circuit Breaker
<1μs Overvoltage Turn-Off, Gentle Shutdown
Controls N-Channel MOSFET
Adjustable Power-Up dV/dt Limits Inrush Current
Reverse Voltage Protection
Power Good Output
Low Current Shutdown
Latchoff (LTC4361-1) or Auto-Retry (LTC4361-2) After Overcurrent
Available in 8-Lead ThinSOT™ and 8-Lead (2mm × 2mm) DFN Packages
```

Comment: whatever102904, that is exactly what I've been looking for, thanks!

Comment: @whatever102904 how do I get the LT4356 to work at 24v 1Amp?

Answer (score 9):

If you want your circuit to be tolerant of over-voltage, you will have to specify up to which voltage, because your protection circuit must be built to withstand that voltage.

If you can afford the drop a diode bridge is a sure way to be polarity independent. You can eliminate the drop by using a relay.

For over-current you will have to decide what to do when you detect over-current. Limit the current to the maximum value? That implies a linear element, and hence (lots of) power dissipation! Another option is to cut of the power to your gadget until power is removed. This implies some memory element, a thyristor can be convenient for this purpose.

Note that your wish not to have a fuse makes a huge difference in cost: otherwise a fuse + power zener diode would do the reverse and over voltage protection, and a current triggered thyristor crowbar would do over-current.

You seemed to be unhappy with the drop for a series diode. You must realize that almost any form of current monitoring will need some voltage drop, and lower drops require a more complex circuit..

Comment: To add to your last point instead of using a diode which drops th voltage by minimum of 0.3V (schottky ) one can go for MOSFET which consumes voltages in the range of tens of millivotls.

Comment: Durgaprasad, can you elaborate on using Mosfet like a diode? thx.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can find umpteen number of ICs for your requirements. Below is for the Linear Technologies' [LTC4361](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/436112fb.pdf). All the LTC43 series are one or the other protectory ICs. You can go through the datasheet of the below IC and design the peripherals accordingly for your requirements. 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are chips that do provide for functions of over voltage detect or over current detect. It can be quite inexpensive to build your own circuit though. There is a reasonably [good article in EDN online](http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4315283/Circuit-breaker-provides-overcurrent-and-precise-overvoltage-protection) which describes a discrete component circuit as shown below:

[image]

A neat feature of the above circuit is that it operates like a circuit breaker and removes the load from the faulted input. It stays removed until reset via a tact switch or the input power is removed.

It is my suggestion that the reverse polarity protection can best be provided via a series Schottky diode in the Vin+ supply line. I also suggest that you design your over voltage detector and over current detector in a manner that leaves the GND of the circuit intact. Someday when your project ideas turn into a real product that you must take off to a lab for emissions and immunity testing you will really appreciate using design techniques that keep a single GND, GND planes and chassis/enclosure references.