# Is reverse polarity protection required for the ZXTR2005Z regulator?

Tags: automotive, linear-regulator, reverse-polarity

I am trying to figure out whether reverse polarity protection is required for the [ZXTR2005Z regulator](https://docs.rs-online.com/4ccb/0900766b8154d64d.pdf).

On the one hand, the datasheet is "suspiciously" explicit that the input voltage must be greater than 10V, on the other hand, if I drop 1V of an automotive supply across an additional protection diode, the whole thing drops out at 11V which seems too high. At cranking there is a chance it would drop out, right?

Comment: Your battery can drop much further than 11V when cranking anyway. Depending what output voltage you're trying to get to an alternative approach might be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "Input Voltage = 10 to 100V" is for **functionality** only, it means the regulator will function when 10 V < \$V_{IN}\$ < 100 V.

The "damaging conditions" are under **Absolute Maximum ratings** and this only gives 100 V as the maximum \$V_{IN}\$.

So the lowest value (including negative) that \$V_{IN}\$ may have **before the device is damaged** is **unspecified**.

So I'd take the **safe option** and make sure that a negative \$V_{IN}\$ can never cause too much current to flow and voltage to develop across the regulator's input. That means **adding a reverse polarity protection** is a good idea.

The are other ways to implement reverse voltage protection **without** adding a voltage drop at the input. The simplest is a (self-resetting) fuse in series with the input and a (fast) diode across the regulator's input that conducts when there's a reverse voltage, see [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164306/reverse-polarity-protection-idea).

There are other solutions as well, some do not require a fuse, just use Google search on "reverse voltage protection circuit" and select the **images** tab.

==================================================================

Let's look in a bit more detail at the circuit in this regulator:

[image]

What happens when \$V_{IN}\$ < 0?

The zener diode will be in forward mode so it will drop up to ~0.7 V, the rest of the voltage will occur across BC junction of the NPN transistor, which will be in forward mode as well!

So a **huge current** can flow when \$V_{IN}\$ < -1.2 V as that voltage will basically be across two diodes in forward mode. For sure these diodes will **break** when the current gets too high.

So yes, reverse voltage protection is really needed.