# Small size clamping device to protect 5V circuit from high voltages

Tags: surge-protection

Are there any small size clamping device or ICs to protect a circuit working on 5V? I would like to protect the circuit from high voltage like 200V - 300V.

Edit: I want to use [SN6501](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn6501.pdf) or [MAX845](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX845.pdf) to make dc-dc converter. The chip should just stop working if Vcc is over the max. rating. So, the output of dc-dc converter is zero and it should be safe. But are there any such devices which will just clamp the input to 5V or protect the circuit until the high voltage is present?

Comment: Sure, a TVS diode will work.  The size will depend on how much energy you want to absorb.  That will depend on the source of the high voltage, the time period that it is applied, and the source impedance between the voltage and the TVS diode.

Comment: Are you looking for mains line protection? Are you wanting every trace to have protection? Can the circuit be enclosed in a case that protects everything except the input and output lines? A lot more description of the problem should be here.

Comment: A similar question has been asked recently (within the last 10 days?), but that may have been closed because the question was too vague, and I can't find it with a search. Please give us some more information to go on. Is the circuit connected to an earth?

Comment: If you want to protect a circuit *power supply* against +/-200V it can be done but it will not be simple nor will it be cheap (assuming your circuit can't tolerate much over 5V without damage and it can't tolerate much under 5V to function, and the current draw is substantial). It it's a 5V signal it's easy.

Comment: @gbulmer http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125172/protection-against-high-voltage but requires 10k+ rep to view. It had some poor answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use TVS protection diode like the [GSOT05C](http://uk.farnell.com/vishay-semiconductor/gsot05c-gs08/diode-tvs-array-5v-sot23/dp/1617673?Ntt=161-7673). In case of overvoltage, the diode opens and dumps all excessive energy in its p-n junction. So it can work only very briefly before overheating and self-destructing.

To enhance the protection, place a low current poly-switch fuse (such as [PSMF01](http://uk.farnell.com/bourns/mf-psmf010x-2/fuse-resettable-ptc-15v-100ma-0805/dp/1294873?Ntt=129-4873)) in series before the input. Once the diode starts conducting, it trips the fuse quickly.

Comment: Here's [another post](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/39602/7036) describing this method.  +1, by the way.

Comment: **If** you can limit the current to 30A, the clamping voltage of a GSOT05C will not exceed 16V according to the datasheet. That might *conceivably* be enough to damage a device with an absolute maximum Vcc of 5.5V.

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental question is: what kind of protection (i.e specific application) you want? Against ESD, load dump, transceiver noise, inductive load transients, failed voltage regulator, ignition pulse...what?

For all above and more, there is a specific length of transients and different energy levels and those different solution with TVS. From the voltage you mention I can guess the cause of transient is the mutual coupling in harness. This happens very often and you have to select a TVS diode with  an energy capability of around 1J in a 1msec pulse