# Designing an over voltage protection for really low voltage

Tags: protection, camera, low-voltage

I'm working on time lapse photography projects and one of the main problems is the voltage supply. So, using a couple of hot glue tubes I was able to create dummy batteries for my camera to connect an external power supply.

I'd like to go further now and use a voltage regulator in order to leave the camera on for longer periods. The problem is that I don't know the maximum voltage nor the current the camera can handle (my camera is a Canon Powershot SX150IS and it works fine with 2 AA 1.5 Volt batteries), so I want to build an overvoltage protection, so whenever the voltage goes over 3V, the power goes down and protects the camera.

I have seen this:

http://www.brighthubengineering.com/consumer-appliances-electronics/68396-over-voltage-and-low-voltage-protection-circuits-easy-home-projects/#imgn_3

as a starting point, but it doesn't seem to fit my needs (high voltage). Do you guys know where I should start? or maybe a better web site I can look at?

Best,

Charlie

Comment: What is the external power supply?

Comment: It consists of a 5V DC cellphone charger with a 0-5V voltage regulator based on LM317 or equivalent.

Comment: related thread: ["Voltage fuse"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/39600/7036)

Comment: Your camera needs 3.2 volts DC at up to 1.5 amperes, so if your charger can supply the current why not just set its output at 3.3 volts and be done with it?

Comment: @EM Fields, where can I find the exact values for the camera's voltage and current? If it requires 1.5A then a cellphone charger won't drive enough current for the camera and I'd have to use a computer power supply with its 3.3V output.

Comment: @Charlie: Canon seems loath to publish them anywhere, so I backed into them [here](http://www.cnet.com/products/canon-ack-800-ac-adapter-kit/specs/).

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

The camera can use NiMH batteries so two in series (check that they are in series - there will be a simple metal piece that connects + to - when they are installed) is 2.4 volts. Current won't matter as long as there is enough. It won't take any more than it needs. You can use the adjustable and set between 2.4 and 3 volts. Or use a cheap 5V wall wart and put 3 diodes (like 1N4001) in series on the + side of the supply. Silicon diodes have a drop of about 0.7 volts so 3 will drop 2.1V of the 5V leaving 2.9 for the camera. If you build the diodes into your plastic or wood battery substitute and use a connector to the power supply, you will have protection against reverse power connection.

Comment: Part 1: If you need more space than a single comment will allow you can always...

Comment: Part2: ...split it up. I don't know if that's kosher, but I haven't gotten any flak so far. :-)

Comment: I like your idea, but there's the problem of the overvoltage.

Comment: @Charlie Modern power supplies use switched mode converters and a voltage surge in the mains will not produce a voltage surge in the regulated power. You can tell a switch mode by its weight. They don't have large mains voltage transformers and are very light compared to older style supplier (which use a transformer and linear regulator like the LM317 you mention). The 1.5A is peak current, like when the auto-focus motor is running at the same time the flash is charging.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to forego the ever-expanding build-a-power-supply route, the easiest/best way out for you might be to just buy a Canon ACK-800 Adapter Kit, which is designed to plug into 110-220 volt 50-60Hz mains and supply the SX150IS with the 3.2 volts at up to 1.5 amperes that it needs to work properly.

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006CFDO) (and a zillion other outfits) has them available online.

Comment: I know there's a commercial way to solve it, but I'd like to design my own device ;)

Comment: Go for it!  Do you need any help?