# Protecting a Schottky diode against negative spikes greater than its specified V_rrm

Tags: automotive, transient, schottky, negative, spike

It appears this can be made to work, but I am not sure how. Related:

[Protection against transient voltage spikes regarding ISO7637-1/2: TVS diode with Schottky diode suitable?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/655681/protection-against-transient-voltage-spikes-regarding-iso7637-1-2-tvs-diode-wit)

> or a 40V schottky plus 18V negative clamp diode (this will be a TVS in series with a rectifier so its forward clamping is eliminated)

What are the parameters of D2 and D3 to be looking at and how to relate them to those of D1 ?

```
V_sp_pos_max = maximum positive spike (automotive environment)
V_f_D2 = forward voltage for D2
```

[image]

Also, since D1 is a Schottky diode its reverse current will naturally be very high at high temperatures. Do I correctly guess this setup will also protect whatever comes after D1 against reverse currents as well ?